# I am using shell to generate images using imagemagick but fail to understand the duplicate images that are generated. Please advice

Tags: imagemagick

I have used flatten but it then does not produce the desired results instead creates a copy in the same image

```
echo -e "${GREEN_BOLD}Generating desired set of images for android${NC}"
cd $android_path
convert DefaultIcon.psd    -resize 400x400\!  iconandroid.psd
>> convert iconandroid.psd -flatten default.png
```

Comment: PSD files contain a first layer that is the flattened layer. So if you want the flattened layer just use DefaultIcon.psd[0]

Comment: I can use defaulticon.psd[0] for the icon but the main idea is to generate only one image or one psd file. I need a way to generate only a single copy of the psd file and further png image.

Comment: There seems to be no difference in the copies created but is that imagemagick by default creates 2 copies

Comment: The command should be `convert iconandroid.psd[0] -resize 400x400\! iconandroid.psd`. It should not produce two output images.

Comment: Yes, it works correctly but I have used convert to create different size images which again genrates two copies. Is there a way out to generate only one single output of the image ?

Comment: Post an image that has this issue and your convert command.

Comment: convert iconandroid.psd default.png is the command that I am currently using.

Comment: Try `convert iconandroid.psd[0] default.png`. Note the [0] to get just the first layer, which is usually the flattened layer. So you do not need to flatten separately.

Comment: Okay, got it , i have also found a solution to use mogrify wherever possible to resize to required size. Thanks !

Comment: Mogrify is old and limited. If you are only converting one image, you should use convert on Imagemagick 6 or magick on Imagemagick 7. Perhaps your Imagemagick install is corrupt if convert does not work and mogrify does.